# Why after Unmarshalling I got different num of bytes but the same result after Marshalling?

Tags: go, byte, marshalling, unmarshalling

I read geojson with

```
  json, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
```

Then I Print result and see this

> [123 32 34 116 121 112 101 34 58 32 34 70 101 97 116 117 114 101 67
>   111 108 108 101 99 116 105 111 110 34 44 10 32 32 32 32 34 102 101 97
>   116 117 114 101 115 34 58 32 91 10 32 32 32 32 32 32 123 32 34 116 121
>   112 101 34 58 32 34 70 101 97 116 117 114 101 34 44 10 32 32 32 32 32
>   32 32 32 34 103 101 111 109 101 116 114 121 34 58 32 123 34 116 121
>   112 101 34 58 32 34 80 111 105 110 116 34 44 32 34 99 111 111 114 100
>   105 110 97 116 101 115 34 58 32 91 49 48 50 46 48 44 32 48 46 53 93
>   125 44 10 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 34 112 114 111 112 101 114 116 105
>   101 115 34 58 32 123 34 112 114 111 112 48 34 58 32 34 118 97 108 117
>   101 48 34 125 10 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 125 44 10 32 32 32 32 32 32
>   123 32 34 116 121 112 101 34 58 32 34 70 101 97 116 117 114 101 34 44
>   10 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 34 103 101 111 109 101 116 114 121 34 58 32
>   123 10 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 34 116 121 112 101 34 58 32 34 76
>   105 110 101 83 116 114 105 110 103 34 44 10 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32
>   32 34 99 111 111 114 100 105 110 97 116 101 115 34 58 32 91 10 32 32
>   32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 91 49 48 50 46 48 44 32 48 46 48 93 44
>   32 91 49 48 51 46 48 44 32 49 46 48 93 44 32 91 49 48 52 46 48 44 32
>   48 46 48 93 44 32 91 49 48 53 46 48 44 32 49 46 48 93 10 32 32 32 32
>   32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 93 10 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 125 44 10
>   32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 34 112 114 111 112 101 114 116 105 101 115 34
>   58 32 123 10 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 34 112 114 111 112 48 34 58
>   32 34 118 97 108 117 101 48 34 44 10 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 34
>   112 114 111 112 49 34 58 32 48 46 48 10 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32
>   125 10 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 125 44 10 32 32 32 32 32 32 123 32 34
>   116 121 112 101 34 58 32 34 70 101 97 116 117 114 101 34 44 10 32 32
>   32 32 32 32 32 32 32 34 103 101 111 109 101 116 114 121 34 58 32 123
>   10 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 34 116 121 112 101 34 58 32 34 80
>   111 108 121 103 111 110 34 44 10 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 34
>   99 111 111 114 100 105 110 97 116 101 115 34 58 32 91 10 32 32 32 32
>   32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 91 32 91 49 48 48 46 48 44 32 48 46 48 93
>   44 32 91 49 48 49 46 48 44 32 48 46 48 93 44 32 91 49 48 49 46 48 44
>   32 49 46 48 93 44 10 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 91
>   49 48 48 46 48 44 32 49 46 48 93 44 32 91 49 48 48 46 48 44 32 48 46
>   48 93 32 93 10 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 93 10 32 32 32
>   32 32 32 32 32 32 125 44 10 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 34 112 114 111
>   112 101 114 116 105 101 115 34 58 32 123 10 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32
>   32 32 34 112 114 111 112 48 34 58 32 34 118 97 108 117 101 48 34 44 10
>   32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 34 112 114 111 112 49 34 58 32 123 34
>   116 104 105 115 34 58 32 34 116 104 97 116 34 125 10 32 32 32 32 32 32
>   32 32 32 32 32 125 10 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 125 10 32 32 32 32 32
>   32 32 93 10 32 32 32 32 32 125]

After than I Unmarshal it and print again and I got this

> {FeatureCollection [{Feature map[prop0:value0] {Point [102
>   0.5]}} {Feature map[prop0:value0 prop1:0] {LineString [[102 0] [103 1] [104 0] [105 1]]}} {Feature map[prop0:value0 prop1:map[this:that]]
>   {Polygon [[[100 0] [101 0] [101 1] [100 1] [100 0]]]}}]}

Than I Marshal it and got this

> [123 34 116 121 112 101 34 58 34 70 101 97 116 117 114 101 67 111 108
>   108 101 99 116 105 111 110 34 44 34 102 101 97 116 117 114 101 115 34
>   58 91 123 34 116 121 112 101 34 58 34 70 101 97 116 117 114 101 34 44
>   34 112 114 111 112 101 114 116 105 101 115 34 58 123 34 112 114 111
>   112 48 34 58 34 118 97 108 117 101 48 34 125 44 34 103 101 111 109 101
>   116 114 121 34 58 123 34 116 121 112 101 34 58 34 80 111 105 110 116
>   34 44 34 99 111 111 114 100 105 110 97 116 101 115 34 58 91 49 48 50
>   44 48 46 53 93 125 125 44 123 34 116 121 112 101 34 58 34 70 101 97
>   116 117 114 101 34 44 34 112 114 111 112 101 114 116 105 101 115 34 58
>   123 34 112 114 111 112 48 34 58 34 118 97 108 117 101 48 34 44 34 112
>   114 111 112 49 34 58 48 125 44 34 103 101 111 109 101 116 114 121 34
>   58 123 34 116 121 112 101 34 58 34 76 105 110 101 83 116 114 105 110
>   103 34 44 34 99 111 111 114 100 105 110 97 116 101 115 34 58 91 91 49
>   48 50 44 48 93 44 91 49 48 51 44 49 93 44 91 49 48 52 44 48 93 44 91
>   49 48 53 44 49 93 93 125 125 44 123 34 116 121 112 101 34 58 34 70 101
>   97 116 117 114 101 34 44 34 112 114 111 112 101 114 116 105 101 115 34
>   58 123 34 112 114 111 112 48 34 58 34 118 97 108 117 101 48 34 44 34
>   112 114 111 112 49 34 58 123 34 116 104 105 115 34 58 34 116 104 97
>   116 34 125 125 44 34 103 101 111 109 101 116 114 121 34 58 123 34 116
>   121 112 101 34 58 34 80 111 108 121 103 111 110 34 44 34 99 111 111
>   114 100 105 110 97 116 101 115 34 58 91 91 91 49 48 48 44 48 93 44 91
>   49 48 49 44 48 93 44 91 49 48 49 44 49 93 44 91 49 48 48 44 49 93 44
>   91 49 48 48 44 48 93 93 93 125 125 93 125]

After Unmarshalling I got the same

> {FeatureCollection [{Feature map[prop0:value0] {Point [102 0.5]}}
>   {Feature map[prop0:value0 prop1:0] {LineString [[102 0] [103 1] [104
>   0] [105 1]]}} {Feature map[prop0:value0 prop1:map[this:that]] {Polygon
>   [[[100 0] [101 0] [101 1] [100 1] [100 0]]]}}]}

Why is that so? Why do I have different number of bytes and why after Unmarshalling these different bytes I got the same result?

Comment: The large amount of `32` in the first output suggests to me that the first array is indented with spaces. The second one isn't. Why not print as strings instead so that things are a bit more clear?

Comment: Thanks! I printed both cases and see that the difference is really in spaces and line breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original file contains many spaces and new-lines, you can see them in your output (`32` = Space). `json.Unmarshal()` will remove all those spaces and `json.Marshal()` won't add them again. If you want to pretty format your second output you can use `json.MarshalIndent()`.